# Shell script nested loop

Tags: bash, shell

I want to produce a list of files between 14 and 22 April. 
The filenames will have the date in the name, e.g. `J0018658.WANCL90A.16Apr2014.214001.STD.txt`. 
I have tried this script.

```
for i in 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22; do
    for x in *$iApr*.txt; do
      echo "$x"
    done
done
```

I am using this on AIX and the default shell is ksh.  However sh and bash are also available.  Here is what works with ksh:

```
for i in 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22; do
    for x in *${i}Apr*.txt; do
        echo "$x"
    done
done
```

Here is what works even better with bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
for i in {14..22}; do
    for x in *${i}Apr*.txt; do
          echo "$x"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) will try to expand a variable called `iApr`, which is not what you want.

Instead, try making your inner for loop look like this:

```
for x in *${i}Apr*.txt; do
```

Also, your outer loop can be similar to the concept in @anubhava's answer:

```
for i in {14..22}; do
```

---

So the script should look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
for i in {14..22}; do
    for x in *${i}Apr*.txt; do
          echo "$x"
    done
done
```

Again, thanks @anubhava for pointing out the necessity of `shopt -s nullglob`

---

About `#!/bin/sh` vs. `#!/bin/bash`:

If you're running Linux, your `/bin/sh` is likely simply a symlink to `/bin/bash`.  From the man page:

> If  bash  is  invoked  with  the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as  closely  as  possible,  while conforming  to the POSIX standard as well.

Comment: Script now looks like:`for i in {14..22}; do
 for x in *${i}Apr*.txt; do
   echo "$x"
 done
done`  However the output is just `*{14..22}Apr*.txt`
done

Comment: Which version of `bash` are you using?  Do you have `!#/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` at the top of the script?  You'll need at least version 3.2 and `!#/bin/bash` to do the `{14..22}` expansion.

Comment: I guess my `sh` is too old.  I switched to `/bin/bash` and it works.  Thanks

Comment: @BrianG see my note about `#!/bin/sh` vs. `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Thanks for the info about sh vs bash.  I am actually using AIX and the default shell is ksh, but sh and bash are both available.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
ls *{14..22}Apr*.txt
```

OR in BASH:

```
shopt -s nullglob; echo *{14..22}Apr*.txt
```